# Search in database using GET method

Tags: php, html, mysql

so I have a question.

I have this project to school, I have a website with a form and database. Basically after successful form validation input is inserted into database and after that they are redirected using echo 'script' to a summary page which will print inputted values.

So on the summary page is a SQL search which is using WHERE clause plus ID stored in URL by GET method from the script. My question is how can I prevent someone changing the ID in the URL and read input from other users.

I was thinking maybe session could work, but I cant think about a reasonable solution. Thank you for help.

Comment: Never use something like a sequential ID in a URL or anything provided to the user. Add a hash value to the table as a reference and use that.

Comment: Don't use an AUTOINCREMENT column for the id, instead use an unguessable string like a UUID v4.

Comment: Oh you are right I never thought of that jesus. But for like items table I can use autoincrement?

Comment: Maybe? Can't possibly answer that given the lack of information.

Comment: I mean like general table not storing sensitive information about a user. Like a product table stroing quantity, name, price ect.

Comment: If it's ok for the information about all the items to be known to everybody, then it's fine to use an autoincrement there.

Comment: Add authentication and authorisation to your site. In other words, the users must log in so that you know who they are. Then when the user submits a search you can restrict it to return only those rows which were originally added by that user (you can store the user ID as an additional field in any tables where you require such security) - the user ID of the logged in user will be held in the Session on the server for the duration of the logged in session, so it can't be manipulated by the user themselves

Answer (score 0):

Non-sequential ids would be a band-aid over the problem.  But at heart, if you want the page to not be public, you need to require them to have a session that restricts what they can see.  Crudely, you can simply return with the redirect a cookie containing the id they are allowed to see and a cryptographic signature that you can verify when they do the get.  Somewhat better is to have the cookie contain a session id, and store session information (the id they are allowed to see) in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```
function encryptIt($q) {
    $cryptKey = 'YourKey_String';
    $qEncoded = openssl_encrypt($q, "AES-128-ECB", $cryptKey);
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt($q) {
    $cryptKey = 'YourKey_String';
    $qDecoded = openssl_decrypt($q, "AES-128-ECB", $cryptKey);
    return( $qDecoded );
}

function testEncryptDecrypt() {
//Get your ID from DB here and format $arData as you want

    $arData = array(
        'id_cust' => 220,
        'id_user' => 45220,
        'extra' => 'toto il est beau mon lavabo',
    );
    $jsonString = json_encode($arData);
    $token = encryptIt($jsonString);
    // use the token in you get request
    $kryptDone = decryptIt($token);
    $dataReturn = json_decode($kryptDone, true);
}
```